# Redux app business logic that doesn't affect the state?

Tags: javascript, redux, redux-thunk

I have an application that utilises Oauth2 "redirect flow" to authenticate users, i.e. users are redirected to another website to log in, and are then redirected back to my site.

The documentation and other sources all seem to claim that business logic should go either in the action creators or in the reducer. However I have a `login()` function that does not change the state in any way, what it does is that it saves the current state of the application as a plain object in localStorage, then redirects the user to the authorisation server. When the user has logged in and is redirected back the state is restored (by another piece of code) and fed as the initial state to my store creator function.

My question: The logic of the `login` function just retrieves the state but doesn't change it in any way so it doesn't belong in the reducer. It also doesn't return an action which is the definition of an action creator. Where in my application structure should I put it?

Is it "ok" to have an action creator that actually doesn't create an action? I'm doing this right now with redux-thunk (because I need to `getState()`) and it works without any problems, but it feels wrong because it's actually not an "action creator", on the other hand I also have a `logout()` function that does return an action so it feels like they should live in the same place. I guess it's kind of a corner case, but not really because I can think of a lot of reasons to save the state in this way and redirect visitors to other sites (or even just save the state without redirecting).

PS. I know there are libraries to sync my redux store with localStorage automagically but this is not exactly the point of the question.

EDIT: Some clarification:

From the [Redux docs](http://redux.js.org/docs/FAQ.html#structure-business-logic) regarding where to put business logic:
*There’s no single clear answer to exactly what pieces of logic should go in a reducer or an action creator.*

Reading on, it's made clear that there are only two places where I'm supposed to put business logic, either in a reducer or an action creator. Now, since what I want to do doesn't affect the state and a reducer by definition affects the state, I'm leaning towards putting this logic in an action creator.

The docs on action creators: *Action creators are exactly that—functions that create actions. It's easy to conflate the terms “action” and “action creator,” so do your best to use the proper term. [...] In Redux action creators simply return an action*

The docs on actions: *Actions are plain JavaScript objects.*

The pseudocode for my login example:

```
function login() {
    // retrieving and serializing the state, then:
    localStorage.set('my_app_id_state', my_serialized_state);
    window.location = url_to_authorization_service;
}
```

This code obviously has no place in an action creator because I'm not returning an action, which is the purpose of an action creator. However I still need to retrieve the state so I can't make it completely independent either.

So again, the question is where do I put this piece of code in my application structure?

Again, the code works and everything is fine, so I guess this is more of an academic question, but it bugs me a LOT that I'm clearly breaking the essential rules of Redux here. Maybe it's just an exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Dan Abramov](https://twitter.com/dan_abramov) replied on twitter, I will settle on the conclusion that this is an exception to the rules outlined in the documentation.

[image: Dan Abramov's reply]

Answer (score 0):

This was a good a question and made realise I was doing something wrong. So hopefully this answer will be helpful at least to both :)

Take this example adapted from the [Real World Redux example](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/55f19b68e91d3c1a14ccd7d4e226e642e167bef8/examples/real-world/actions/index.js#L21):

A private function

```
function oauth(url) {
 return (dispatch) => {
   dispatch({
    type: types.OAUTH_LOGIN,
    url
   });
 };
}
```

is called by the action creator (which returns a function)

```
export function loginToApi(redirectUrl) {
  return (dispatch) => {
    return dispatch(oauth(redirectUrl))
  }
}
```

The action in turn is then called in the component, like so:

```
login() {
 return this.props.dispatch(loginToApi());
}
```

So one way to answer your question is to put your business logic inside a private method, which is then called by the action creator.

There's probably a more elegant way, but this is how is done in the docs I mentioned above.

Regarding your login logic for storing the state in local storage: I don't think you need this. Redux store is managing the state for you.

Comment: Hi, thank you for taking the time to answer. I'm sorry if my question was confusing, I'm trying to give an example where I need to do something in my app that doesn't affect the state of it. From the Redux docs: "Actions are payloads of information that send data from your application to your store. [...] Actions are plain JavaScript objects. Actions must have a type property ... " In your example you are not returning a plain object, and I'm not doing that either in my login function. Thus, neither of us are following the spec for what an action should really be and that's the problem here :)

Comment: I edited my question now, maybe it's more clear now what I'm asking.

Comment: Ha, good point! Let me edit my answer. In the meantime, have you seen this https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/55f19b68e91d3c1a14ccd7d4e226e642e167bef8/examples/async/actions/index.js#L38 I think your solution is in there

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think that I'm getting any wiser. Asynchronous action creators does actually not return plain objects so I guess maybe I should read the docs as rules for a "pure" redux app i.e. without any middleware, but that sounds weird since middleware is one of Redux's most powerful features (there are very few cases when you don't need any middleware at all). And in the end an asynchronous action creator is invoking other action creators and eventually effectively does what it's supposed to - dispatch plain object actions that affects the state.

Comment: Please check my edited answer. You don't have to use a middleware. That's recommended only if your chaining async actions.

Comment: I saw your edited answer now, why would I want to dispatch an action though? I don't need to make the reducer react and that is the purpose of dispatching actions (also see my previous comment). Also I do need to use thunk or similar middleware in order to return a function from an action creator.

Comment: At this point, I can only recommend not to take rules too literally; sorry I can't be of more help.

Comment: No problem, thank you for the discussion. I tweeted Dan Abramov, hopefully he'll see it. But yes, I'm going to keep breaking the rules for now.